Multidimensional Hardy inequality
I am having a really hard time in finding references in which is stated rigorously and proved what I think is called the multidimensional Hardy inequality which is like :
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}|\nabla u|^p\,dx\geq\left(\frac{N-p}{p}\right)^p\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}\frac{|u|^p}{|x|^p}\,dx$$
What are the necessary & sufficient hypothesis on $f, N, p$ such that the inequality is correct ?
Where can I find some references about its precise statement and proof (also about the fact that the constant is optimal) ?

I answer my own question in case someone else will look for references about this fact.
Proof of the multidimensional Hardy inequality can be found in

A. A. Balinsky, W. D. Evans, R. T. Lewis, The Analysis and Geometry of Hardy's Inequality, Universitext, Springer, Cham, 2015, Corollary 1.2.6.
V. G. Maz'ya, Sobolev Spaces, Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften, Springer-Verlag, Heidelberg, 2011, Section 1.3.1.


I think you may see Page 520, Section 4, Eq. (4) in this paper:
Davies E.B. and Hinz A.M., Explicit constants for Rellich inequalities in $L_p(\Omega)$, Mathematische Zeitschrift, 227, pp. 511-523, 1998.
